# how to unlock locked tables explicitly in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have a master stored procedure which calls multiple stored procedures to write data on multiple tables, around 9-10 in one go. And once all the inserts are done, there is one commit for all of them.
I want to use data concurrency and lock tables in individual sub procedures, which does not have any commit, so

> LOCK TABLE table_name IN lock_mode

will work, but will hold the table until rest of the data is been inserted in the respective tables called after this and the final commit or rollback is called, which is not a good idea. Also I don't have `dbms_lock` opened.

Will locking all the tables in my master stored procedures, or locking the tables in the respective sub-stored procedures is the only option??

My master stored procedure looks like this

```
PROCEDURE POPULATE_ALL(P_ASOFDATE DATE, P_ENTITY VARCHAR2) IS
    BEGIN
      POPULATE_ABC_BOOK(P_ASOFDATE);
      POPULATE_XYZ(P_ASOFDATE, P_ENTITY);
      POPULATE_DEF(P_ASOFDATE, P_ENTITY);
      POPULATE_AAA(P_ASOFDATE, P_ENTITY);
    commit;
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       rollback;
       P_ERROR := SQLERRM;
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
                              '*** Unexpected Error in POPULATE_ALL -->' ||
                              P_ERROR);
   END POPULATE_ALL;
```

where POPULATE_XYZ is populating XYZ table.

Comment: Why are you explicitly locking tables in the first place?  I've dealt with a lot of Oracle systems and I've yet to see one where explicit table locking was useful.  What do you mean about having `dbms_lock` "opened"?  Are you saying that you aren't allowed to use `dbms_lock` for some reason?  Why would you be allowed to explicitly lock a table but not acquire a user-defined lock?

Comment: Yes, I am not allowed to use `dbms_lock`

Comment: Why are you explicitly locking tables in the first place?  Why would you be allowed to explicitly lock a table but not acquire a user-defined lock?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't need locking at all. Just do your inserts without any explicit locking.

There is no way to unlock table in the middle of transaction. This operation has no ANY sense in Oracle; it can be useful only if database supports dirty reads. Table lock finishes only if

- commit,
- rollback or
- rollback to savepoint before lock established

executed.

Comment: Consider scenario... Transaction T1 changes Table ABC & inserted a row value to 123... the second transaction T2 entered, while T1 still working. T2 changed to 789. T1 commits and everything good. T2 occurred exception and rolled back. but since T2 changed the value to 789 and T1 commited. What will be the value in table ABC, 123 or 789?? if its 789, then the data would be wrong. Please explain

Comment: @deejay - I don't follow.  If T1 hasn't committed the insert, T2 can't see the row (it's not committed) so it can't possibly update it until after T1 commits because it can't see the row until then.

Comment: @deejay, did you ever listen about [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)? :) You can try to reproduce this scenario and you'll see it's just impossible. Transaction T2 has no chance to update 'row value' before commit of T1.

Comment: Well I know about ACID :) and thanks for clearing me again on the same.

Comment: You're welcome. Generally... locking is an important and fragile area. Don't try to introduce your own approaches until you know it well. Trust the database or consult the senior developer when you're in doubt.